# Not producing databinding classes

Tags: android, data-binding

I am working on an example from one of my Android programming books.  The book was written when there was still a findViewById method, so I'm trying to translate it to use databinding. However, after adding the necessary layout root and the two classpaths to the build.gradle file, the databinding classes are not being generated.

Does anyone have any ideas, help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {



repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data class="SudokuBinding">
    variable name="user" type="com.example.flash.sudoku.Sudoku"
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="30dip"
    tools:context="com.example.flash.sudoku.Sudoku">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_title"
            android:textSize="24.5sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_game_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_label" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exit_label" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing below in your **build.gradle**,

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Also your layout file should be wrapped in layout tag something like this

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        >
<data class="SudokuBinding">
    variable name="user" type="com.example.flash.sudoku.Sudoku"
</data>

....your layout goes here...
....
....
....

</layout>
```

you can checkout my sample project here @https://github.com/akhgupta/databindingDemo

Comment: I enabled databinding in build file. I have also added the namespaces, but now I am getting a duplicate attribute error in the landscape version of the activity. Do I need the root tag layout in both files? I also have an about activity that I need bound.

Comment: I finally have the binding files, however I get an error on the statement in the landscape version of activity_main where I am defining the binding variable

Answer (score 0):

@user182162
Seems like you have two versions of the layout: one for landscape and the other for portrait. 
Those file should be unique. 
Both files need to have `<layout></layout>` as root tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need the data element in both